# XAMPP: Mercury (Mail Transfer Agent) not working

Tags: email, thunderbird, xampp, pop3, mta

Here is my setup:

---

I have installed XAMPP as Administrator and am running it as Administrator.
I have an entry in my Windows 7 hosts file listing "127.0.0.1 rainbow.com"
as the fictitious domain which I am using on my development machine.
I configured an admin user in the BitNami Magento module for XAMPP
named johndoe@rainbow.com . I have added this user in Mercury via:

XAMPP Mercury Admin Button -> Configuration menu title -> Manage Local Users...

and added johndoe@rainbow.com using a specific "Mail Password" and "APOP Secret".

I have installed Mozilla Thunderbird.

---

Here is what's not working:

1. When I send an email to johndoe@rainbow.com from Magento's forgotten password
   recovery in the admin panel, I don't see it in Mercury? What should I do?
2. In Mozilla Thunderbird I see Tools -> Account Settings...
   and Tools -> Options...
   as these seem to be the places where I configure Thunderbird.
   I have inserted my email address under Options... and set the
   server name to rainbow.com in Options... -> Server Settings.

   However I don't see where I insert the "Mail Password" and
   "APOP Secret" in Thunderbird. In fact, I do not see anywhere
   any configurable settings for POP3; I only see IMAP configuration
   settings. So when I try to send mail via Thunderbird, I get the
   following error message:

   "An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  Service not available,
   closing channel..  Please verify that your email address is correct in your Mail preferences
   and try again."

   All I have in my inbox is a message saying "Welcome to Pegasus Mail!" from David Harris.
   I thought Prgasus was a client like Thunderbird, and that Mercury (not Pegasus) was the
   mail server, where have I gone wrong?
3. When I close the window entitled Mercury/32 which I opened via the Admin button in the
   Mercury row in XAMPP Control Panel v.3.2.1, by clicking the x on the upper right hand
   corner of the window, Mercury crashes with the messages:

18:46:55  [mercury]     Status change detected: stopped
18:46:55  [mercury]     Error: Mercury shutdown unexpectedly.
18:46:55  [mercury]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:46:55  [mercury]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:46:55  [mercury]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:46:55  [mercury]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:46:55  [mercury]     If you need more help, copy and post this
18:46:55  [mercury]     entire log window on the forums

Why should closing the admin window make Mercury stop, and then crash in the manner?

---

Conclusion:

I am trying to use Mercury to test email features before going live, but am unable
even to send a simple email to myself and view it in Thunderbird. Any help with
this is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

i encountered problem with email sending with XAMPP installed mail server Mercury. During installation there missed obligate folder QUEUE and sending process breaking. Just create this folder in mercury directory and all will be fine. Thanks to this post http://community.pmail.com/forums/thread/38814.aspx

Comment: note to myself it is QUEUE not QUEQUE :)